# RequireJS doesn't always load modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, underscore.js

20% of the time, the scripts fail loading while using RequireJS.

The additional files that I am using throu the application require, besides the JS libraries, the base.js file, which contains configurations and some setup for underscore & backbone. Without these settings, the other files won't work.

The script tag in the  is the following:

```
<script data-main="http://*path*/js/common" src="http://*path*/js/lib/require.js"></script>
```

The common.js file is

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        underscore: {
            exports: "_"
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ["jquery", "underscore"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        base: {
            deps: ["backbone"]
        }
    },
    paths: {
        jquery: [
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min',
            'http://*path*/media/admin/js/lib/jquery.min'
        ],
        base: 'http://*path*/media/admin/js/base',
        backbone: 'http://*path*/media/admin/js/lib/backbone',
        underscore: 'http://*path*/media/admin/js/lib/underscore'
}
```

});

The base.js file, with the settings for backbone, underscore and jQuery, contains:

```
define(['jquery', 'backbone', 'underscore'], function(jQuery, Backbone, _) {
    //CODE
    return var;
});
```

And the other files contain

```
define(['base'], function(var) {
    //CODE
});
```

In the page I am loading the files using:

```
require(['common'], function() {
    require(['page/file'], function() {
        //CODE
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong, why jQuery, underscore and backbone fail loading sometimes and how can I fix this?

The error message is:

```
GET http://*host*/backbone.js 404 (Not Found) require.js:1

Uncaught Error: Script error for: backbone
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

Comment: Why are you returning var? Surely this causes an error?

Comment: Could you post the exact error message?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that this is the *only* problem but this shim should be removed:

```
base: {
    deps: ["backbone"]
}
```

You've shown a `base.js` file that calls `define`. The rule is simple: if your module calls `define`, then you use `define` to set dependencies, and the return value of the function you pass to `define` to set the value of your module; if your module does *not* call `define`, then you need a shim to set dependencies and determine the value of the module (if needed).